# what are the ipc libs to communicate between a python and an haskell process?

Tags: python, haskell, architecture, ipc

I am considering the general architecture of my next project. For the back-end, haskell looks like a very good fit, but not for the front-end, where python would be better and likely easier to code. The heavy computations would be done in haskell, and the result displayed in a gui built with python.

So, I need to pick the right conduit and the right format to communicate between these two processes.

The message sent from python to the haskell process would be quite simple, like a document with a few but diverse values. (json could be used for that I suppose.)

But the message from the haskell to the python process would be much more heavy with a big (float) arrays. That's where I need to be more careful : whatever libs I use will need to have a fast implementation in python and to be reasonably stable in haskell.

So, what are the options ?

Comment: Yes, it gave me no meaningful result. I think it's not very searchable for three reasons. First, communicating between python and haskell is not very common. Second, it is hard to see what are the best libs in the haskell ecosystem (I am not very familiar with it). Third, what is good enough for small messages may or may not work for messages with big arrays in them.

Comment: Really? Because this google search returns at least two pages on this topic in the first five results: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=haskell+python

Comment: @Marcin: Only one here, and only three on that entire page; however, they are all about the binding/embedding solutions, while this question is primarily about serialisation formats for IPC. I don't think the hostility is warranted; this is a reasonable question with a large variety of possible answers.

Comment: @ehird: It's reasonable to ask, but SO is full of questions from people who couldn't be bothered to do even the most rudimentary research. This is not something to be encouraged.

Comment: @Marcin: Well, since none of the Google results you linked to were directly relevant, and Lionel has said they did try searching first, I'm not sure what additional research you expect; I've tried a few other searches and they don't turn up much of relevance, and definitely nothing like a comparison between available solutions.

Comment: @ehird: (a) No reason is given why it has to be IPC rather some form of in-process technology; (b) The links from that search cover a number of IPC options for both languages, including CORBA; and (c) there's also this, suggesting that LionelBarret didn't even search SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015447/calling-haskell-functions-from-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using google's protocol buffers over zeromq at our company. It's quite happily shuffling data between python, C++ and C# code and I've had a play with haskell successfully too.

Essentially you could split this up into two concerns, serialization and transport.

As ehird mentions their answer there are a multitude of options for serialization. I'd recommend protocol buffers having used it a lot, but I've heard good things about thrift and there's also msgpack.org too, which seems pretty solid.

Transport wise I hands down recommend zeromq, it's awesome! It supports a wide variety of messaging patterns and it's screaming fast. Here's a little example of zmq Resources and Sinks for the conduit library (I haven't released it yet):
https://github.com/boothead/zeromq-conduit

Comment: In fact, I just looked at msgpack again, and the RPC stuff looks very good. RPC is a bit painful in protobuf with python.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [hprotoc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hprotoc) package doesn't export any modules, and [protocol-buffers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/protocol-buffers) doesn't build as of the latest release; those were the only protocol buffer libraries I found on Hackage. So I'm not sure using protocol buffers from Haskell is practical...

Comment: IIRC, when the protocol buffer lib was released, it was very slow in python (the python lib was pure python). Do you know if this has changed ? edit: just got eihrd comment, I suppose this rules out pbuffers if the haskell version is not updated. I'll try to contact the lib maintainer.

Comment: @LionelBarret, PB is fast enough for my purposes in python, but then absolute speed isn't our aim... There is a faster protocol buffers package released by Greplin: https://github.com/Greplin/fast-python-pb. Shame about the protocol-buffers package, I used it a while ago, but not really seriously

Answer (score 5):

I would consider using the [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) or [blaze-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder) packages from Haskell to define your own binary serialisation format, and then writing code to manually unpack it in Python (e.g. using [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)). This is likely to be a pain if you have a lot of structures to transfer, but if there's only one or two, then this is likely to be more compact and simpler than finding a binary serialisation format that's well-supported in both languages.

cereal handles both serialisation and deserialisation, but blaze-builder only does serialisation; on the other hand, I think blaze-builder is faster. cereal's primary purpose is serialising something in a format you're not particularly picky about so you can read it back later with Haskell, meaning it uses a type-class extensively, so you have to be careful about using standard serialisations which do undesirable things like serialise arbitrary bignum `Integer`s rather than fixed-size integers, while blaze-builder is more about custom formats. Still, it's pretty easy to use cereal with a custom format, and if you want to deserialise the structures from Haskell too, it's the obvious choice.

A quick glance at Hackage shows a well-maintained [BSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson) package; that might be a good option if your structures are complex, but otherwise might be overkill.

I think using JSON for the Python→Haskell transport is probably the best idea; while you lose the nicety of having the same serialisation format being used both ways, JSON is very standard, and well-supported in Haskell by [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson). If you choose BSON for the Haskell→Python route, that could work too.

Other options I can think of:

- There's two confusingly-named bindings for Apache Thrift on Hackage: [Thrift](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Thrift) and [thrift](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thrift); it seems like the former is being deprecated in favour of the latter. I don't really know anything about Thrift, though, so I can't say whether this would be helpful or not.
- You could [embed the Python code](https://john-millikin.com/articles/ride-the-snake/) within the Haskell process using [cpython](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpython) or [MissingPy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingPy) (though the latter seems to be unmaintained).
- You could use the FFI to export functions from Haskell, and then import them from Python using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: I think the package you mean is called "[cpython](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpython)" and not "haskell-cpython."

Comment: @dflemstr: Oh, thanks; the article I linked refers to it as the latter.

Comment: I would like to avoid unnecessay complexity for the first version/prototype. Embedding (which could be also done with [cython](http://cython.org/)) adds a layer of complexity. IPC and keeping the two process separate  seems more straightforward to me and open the doors to others front-end.

Comment: (for the record: your answer was as good as Ben above, but I can assign it only once)