# Haskell function in Python FFI

Tags: python, haskell, ffi

I try to use haskell function in my Python program using FFI.

My function is like f :: String -> String

anyone can help me?

i have another function f2 :: [(Double,Double,Double)] -> ((Double,Double,Double),(Double,Double,Double))

edit:

i found some information here: https://github.com/nh2/call-haskell-from-anything

i know how to call function like fib :: Int -> Int in Python

ex.

```
module Example where

import Foreign.C.Types

fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci n = fibs !! n
    where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
fibonacci_hs = fromIntegral . fibonacci . fromIntegral

foreign export ccall fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
```

but i don't know how to make funciton :: String -> String callable in Python

Comment: What kind of FFI? How do you do it?

Comment: A first step is to change the list into a contiguous data type such as `Vector Double` and pass a pointer and length.

Comment: @gspr: I think the library that OP is using works on a slightly higher level of abstraction, so that a list is probably easier to handle

Comment: Some of these functions might be helpful: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-C-String.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Haskell functions from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015447/calling-haskell-functions-from-python)

Answer (score 1):

Just as you need to wrap your fib function on `Int` to a function on `CInt`, you similarly need to wrap your function on `String` as a function on `CString`: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-C-String.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options for calling `Haskell` from `Python`

There is a open source project [HaPy](https://github.com/sakana/HaPy) which provides a nice and easy to use binding. Char and String Haskell types are supported here.

There is also the `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` method with an example [here](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-from-python). You will need to incorporate sclv's answer with `CString`.

See this answer for an example on how to use [CString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812166/how-to-pass-a-string-from-haskell-to-c)