# Python and functional language interop

Tags: python, functional-programming, interop

My current primary programming language is python. There are lots of things I like about it, but I also like functional languages. Not enough to do an entire program in them, but definitely for certain functionality, that fits the functional mould well.

Of course .NET is amazing in this regard, having both ironpython and F#. But considering the ironpython support for the scientific python ecosystem is still dodgy last time I checked, .NET is not much of an option for me. I am a bit shocked at the apparent lack of tools to facilitate interop between cpython and say, Haskell. They are both mature languages with large communities, that seem like such a nice match to me.

Is there something about their architecture that makes them ill-compatible that im missing, or is this just something awesome that is still waiting to happen?

To clarify; there are some half-baked projects out there, but I am thinking of something that parallels the awesomeness of Weave, pycuda, or boost. Something that automates all the plumbing inherent in interop with just a few annotations.

Comment: You could interop between Cythons and Haskell's C FFI

Comment: Right. Haskell has interop with C, and python has interop with C. So in theory it should be possible to have my python list automagically get casted to a Haskell list, and vice versa. But there are no tools for neatly abstracting such boilerplate away, the advantages are quickly overshadowed, in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's a culture question. This is like ... making AWK scripts usable from Scala via Java Scripting Services?

Comment: Not an answer to the question as posed, but have you seen hyphen? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015447/calling-haskell-functions-from-python/33586298#33586298). It seems a little more extensively developed than some python/haskell bridges out there.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use unix pipes, and just write a Haskell program, and also write a Python program, and have them communicate over text.  Haskell and Python even share the same syntax for lists, so it's really easy to pipe data from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to:

> Is there something about their architecture that makes them
> ill-compatible that im missing, or is this just something awesome that
> is still waiting to happen?

I think it is about the people doing these languages:

There are not much people who want to do Haskell and Python at the same time.

1. to make use of both languages (liek Haskell and Python) at the same time you either could go via the C-Interface or create a protocol both languages speak.

   Both are fairly advanced, limiting the number of people who could do it. Sure there would be also tradeoffs which make it difficult to use the full power of both languages.
2. I am using Python and although I know some Haskell, I do not program it. I am a bit stuck in object-orientation, telling me that some day a problem will decide for me that it can better be solved in Haskell than python. That problem did not yet occur because my first thought is: I know how to do it in Python. I think other 'experts' face that problem, too.
3. You start thinking in a language. I think that Haskell has a totally different way of thinking with its functional style, no side-effects. To get into this thinking I need to forget or not use my Python knowledge. Switching between these two ways of thinking requires some strength.

Wrapping it up: because that two languages are not so close they stay apart. It is hard to do both and there are not many or easy ways to practice doing both.

Comment: To summarize: you don't really see the point. But trust me: using functional languages becomes a lot more appealing when they are seamlessly integrated. Don't tell the functional fanatics, but some tasks lend themselves far better to one style or the other. Putting a pixel in a framebuffer in a functional language just feels like putting a square peg in a round hole, f.i. That is what is stopping functional languages for me. I am already using countless languages at the same time anyway, so that's not the obstacle for many people. Hundereds of lines of boilerplate to wrap a 5 line function is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that any answer to this question would be remiss without considering the inertia of object-oriented and imperative languages relative to functional ones.  Consider the following situation, beginning with the fact that functional languages are not taught at nearly the frequency that object-oriented or imperative languages are at the secondary, university, or graduate level.  As User mentions, there is significant momentum involved as a programmer concerning one's choice of language.  For example, during the course of a typical CS degree at a four year University, one may learn a handful of languages and more than likely, not one of them is a functional language.  This typical graduate will then proceed to work in industry, where, after programming for 40+ hours per week for one's job, it is very difficult to then take time to, not only learn an entirely new language, but to learn a language that operates completely differently from the one's one already knows.  On top of all of this, there is the drawback that functional languages are not nearly as useful in industry as object-oriented or imperative one's are.  One can see that given this current state, it is understandable that the interoperability between Python and Haskell is not what some programmers would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use Haskell to Python bindings, what would you do in each language?

If you consider binding C and Python, for example, you use C when you need the speed boost, or when you need to push bits around, and you are using Python when want to be expressive and concise.  It's common that you have a pair of languages, one for most of the logic, and one that you can drop *down* to for speed, at the cost of clarity.  The more of a gap between the languages, the more you can gain from switching.

If we were to bind Haskell and Python, it is less clear what you'd get out of it.  I wouldn't drop from Python into Haskell just for speed, since Haskell, while fast, isn't as fast as C.  But if I was using Haskell, when would I use Python?  Python isn't more expressive than Haskell, not like comparing C and Python.

I think that most of the time, it's easier to just `import` [functools](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html), and program functionally in Python, instead of having to convert objects into some Haskell representation, do some work, and then convert it back.

Though, if you really wanted it, Cython would make it easy to write functions that Haskell's FFI can use.

Comment: Interesting observation.

Comment: I would want to use python for things that are naturally expressed as mutable code, and Haskell for math-y inner loops, where the immutability of Haskell allows me to write more obviously correct code (which is also way faster than python; and approaching that of C). But the mutable/immutable conceptual division would be the main appeal to me.

Comment: Would you like me to flesh out the FFI to show how to bind a Haskell function in Python?  (I'd need to learn a bit myself too).